# Icon for indicator-cpufreq using Faenza icon theme

Tags: themes, indicator, icons

I installed `indicator-cpufreq` but it doesn't work with the Faenza icon theme. Is there a way to make the indicator use the icon from the `ubuntu-mono-dark` icon theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Goto the installed icon folder (`.icon` in home folder if you installed for current user)
- Open `index.theme` file in gedit or any text editor.
- In `inherit` field put the backup icon theme name at front.

An example

`Inherits=ubuntu-mono-dark,gnome,hicolor`

So the line means, if no icon found in this icon-theme, search in `ubuntu-mono-dark`, if not available in ubuntu-mono-dark searach icon in `gnome`, if not available in gnome set take from `hicolor`

Comment: It worked perfectly but i just edited the index.theme on /usr/share/icons/Faenza . And i'm sorry for the late answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the icon theme using a package (into `/usr/share/icons/`) or you don't want to modify the original theme, you can create a mono version by copying the folder `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark` into the `.icons` folder in your home folder. Rename it to what ever you want, such as `faenza-mono-dark`.

Then, in the folder you just copied, open up the `index.theme` file and edit these lines

```
Name=Ubuntu-Mono-Dark
Comment=Smooth modern theme designed to be intuitive.
Inherits=Humanity-Dark,gnome,hicolor
```

To look like this:

```
Name=Faenza-Mono-Dark
Comment=Smooth modern theme designed to be intuitive.
Inherits=Faenza,gnome,hicolor
```

What this does is create a new icon theme which adds the dark icons found in `ubuntu-mono-dark` to the Faenza icon theme.

Comment: Got perfectly, thanks!! perfectly. I'm sorry for the late answer. :)